# Why PHP script returns empty string on server

Tags: php, https

I run this in localhost and it works. In the server the PHP script returns empty string.

The PHP file containing the script:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
                function repstr($str) {
                   return str_replace("x", "y", $str);
                }

                echo stripslashes(urldecode(repstr($_REQUEST["par"])));
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Called URL in localhost:

https://localhost/myscript.php?par=x123

on the server:

https://domain.com/myscript.php?par=x123

Both return HTML. But localhost has expected content in td element, server td has no content.

What could it be?

Edit: I currently don't have access to the PHP file in the server.

Comment: Did you take a look at the page source? are there any warnings or errors there?

Comment: You aren't passing the variable `code` to the URL. You're passing `par`.  Does `$_GET['par']` work?

Comment: Check the PHP error log.

Comment: Try adding var_dump($_REQUEST), to see what you are getting.

Comment: Note, it is not necessary to call `urldecode()` on `$_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST/$_COOKIE`. PHP does so automatically.

Comment: @Yarino Nope. No errors or warnings. Returned HTML looks fine, besides the td is empty (although there's some space inside).

Comment: @Michael, corrected, made an error making simpler version for SO.

Comment: what is your var_dump($_REQUEST) output ??

Comment: Ok. Now I could modify the php file on server and add var_dump($_REQUEST); and oh surprise, the parameter isn't listed?? But I see it clearly in the URL. What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a configuration diffence between my localhost and the server. The GET parameter is very long and the server didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean:

```
return str_replace("x", "y", $str);
```

?

Comment: agh, yes, error making simpler version of the code. Corrected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's Working. Make sure that you are having correct permissions to execute the code. Minimum will be 755.